# AppArmor Profile: Deny internet access

Tags: networking, ip, apparmor

I want to deny the internet permission for some applications. Therefore, I tried first to deny the internet permission for ping, but it doesn't work.

Here is the profile of `/etc/apparmor.d/bin.ping`

```
/{usr/,}bin/ping {
  #include <abstractions/base>
    # block ipv4 acces
    deny network inet,
    # ipv6 
    deny network inet6,
    # raw socket
    deny network raw,
}
```

But the pinging still happens after restarting `apparmor` with

```
/etc/init.d/boot.apparmor restart
 ping google.de
PING google.de (64.15.112.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (64.15.112.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=11.8 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (64.15.112.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=15.3 ms
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mentioned that I'm running OpenSuse 13.1

Comment: I would suggest you to close this question since this issue was resolved on an OpenSUSE AppArmor forum - https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/498827-AppArmor-Profile-Deny-internet-access .Isn't that you asking? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must either delete the `#include <abstractions/base>` line, or add a `#include <tunables/global>` line to the top of the file, before the profile is defined. This is because abstractions/base uses variables defined in tunables/global.

Answer (score 0):

the doc is here: https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/Documentation
file permissions & co there under: https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/QuickProfileLanguage#file-permissions

recommended watch as gentle intro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRZ59lxLlOY

lets pick example atril pdf viewer, if there does not exist a profile make one:

```
sudo aa-genprof /usr/bin/atril # do stuff in the app to elicit events
sudo aa-logprof # to adjust profile, written to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.atril
```

exmaple profile, enforce via
`sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.atril` and try clicking a link in a pdf, the audit `sudo dmesg -w` will show `apparmor="DENIED"`

```
# Last Modified: Sun Dec 13 23:28:03 2020
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/atril {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/lightdm>

    # block ipv4 acces
    deny network inet,
    # ipv6 
    deny network inet6,
    # raw socket
    deny network raw,

    owner /** rwm,
}
```

blocks the app: help->about->website from opening; adjust other appropriate  via the aa-logproof